# how to use bubble as series type in kendo stockChart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

how to use bubble as series type in kendo StockChart?

I have tried the following code but it is not working

```
<script>
$("#chart").kendoStockChart({
  series: [
    {
      type: "bubble",
      data: [
        { x: 1, y: 2, size: 3 },
        { x: 4, y: 5, size: 6 },
        { x: 7, y: 8, size: 9 }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
</script>
```

is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The stockChart only supports the following series types:

- area
- column
- line
- candlestick, ohlc
- bullet

See documentation here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/stock-chart/configuration/series.type

For bubble charts, you would use the Chart object: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.type